# Parsing VS Treating as string (JSON)

Tags: java, json, performance, parsing

Hey fellow programmers,

I am working on a JAVA application where speed is key. I need to deal with a stream of JSON (Requests to the server return a json object that I continuously parse to analyze it later on). The Json object is about 2000 characters long, so I was wondering if it wouldn't be quicker to just treat it as a string (using indexOf, substring  etc... ) instead of using a JSON Parser. (I used both Jackson and Json-lib without noticeable difference) ? Will it save me a couple milli-seconds ?

Thank you !

Comment: Depends on how much of the data are you parsing.  If you're just getting one value out of it, obviously, it'll be faster to grab that piece of it.

Comment: If speed is an important consideration for your use case I'd recommend trying both implementations and seeing how much of a difference it makes for your data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you need to know from it, but in general, I think it's better to use a JSON parser. The parser will be highly optimized, so it will beat your own attempts if you need to read many values. Also, the parser will ignore whitespace, while you have to take care of it explicitly.

Checking something yourself is harder than you think. For instance, if you need to know if a property 'x' exists, you cannot just check for the existance of the string `x`, because it can also be part of a value. You cannot look for `x:`, because maybe there is a space between them. And if you found `x`, do you know if it is in the right place? Is it part of the right object, or maybe of a sub-object you didn't expect there to be at all?

Before you know it, you are writing a parser yourself.

If you can't notice the difference, don't bother and use the parser, because it is the easiest, safest and most flexible choice. Only start optimizing if you need to.